# The Label Isn't Updating

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x

```
def timer(self, delay, counter):
        while self.exitPro == False:
            while self.isOn:
                time.sleep(delay)
                counter += 1
                self.timed = counter
                print(self.timed)
```

Def Timer Is A Thread that is constantly running in the backround and is updating (This is working)

```
def main(self):
    timer = Thread(target=self.timer, args=(1, 0))
    timer.start()


    root = Tk()
    root.title("Jamie Stopwatch")
    v = IntVar()
    v.set(self.timed)
    stopwatch = ttk.Label(root, textvariable=v)
    stopwatch.grid(row=1, column=2)
```

Now i need the label to update the the value of the timer.

Comment: Are you asking how to solve a threading problem, or how to write a stopwatch in tkinter. You certainly don't need threads to create a stopwatch in tkinter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `after`:

```
def main(self):
    [...]
    self.stopwatch_value = IntVar()
    stopwatch = ttk.Label(root, textvariable=self.stopwatch_value)
    stopwatch.grid(row=1, column=2)
    root.after(self.update, 500)

def update(self):
    self.stopwatch_value.set(self.timed)
    root.after(self.update, 500)
```

Comment: root.after(self.update, 100)
AttributeError: 'AO' object has no attribute 'update'

Comment: I've given you the `update`-method that you need to insert in your `AO`-class.

Comment: Yeah root = Tk() is definied in main(self) so it is saying that root cant be found